# Steps and Rules of solving this function?

Tags: functions

The function $\dfrac 1{3-\log_5(x)}$ is given. I know the answer, but what I really need to know is how to actually find the domain without outside help.

Comment: At which points does the denominator give you zero values or is undefined (meaning the domain of the base $5$ log function)? You just need to exclude them.

Comment: Also check the domain of a log function.

Comment: I might as well remove this, I over thought this question. I see now that $log_5(125)$ equals 3, which provides error at this point.

Comment: Also $x = 0$ as that log is undefined there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first it must be $$x>0$$ and the denominator must be $$3-\log_5(x)\neq 0$$
if so we obtain $$\log_5 5^3=\log_5 (x)$$ thus we get $$x=5^3$$ thus we have
$$x>0$$ and $$x\ne 5^3$$